# How can I create a bi_grams from this list?

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

How can I create a bi_grams from this list ?

```
text = ['to','be',',','or','not','to','be',',','that','is','the','question',':']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
text = ['to','be',',','or','not','to','be',',','that','is','the','question',':']
bi_grams = [(text[t1], text[t1+1]) for t1 in range(len(text)-1)]
bg = [(x, bi_grams.count(x)) for x in list(set(bi_grams))]
bg.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
result = {x[0]: x[1] for x in bg}
print(result)
```

output

```
{('to', 'be'): 2, ('be', ','): 2, ('that', 'is'): 1, ('question', ':'): 1, ('is', 'the'): 1, ('the', 'question'): 1, (',', 'or'): 1, ('not', 'to'): 1, ('or', 'not'): 1, (',', 'that'): 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond,It was really helpful.                                                                       what if I want my output be like this?   {     ('to', 'be'): 2,   ('be', ','): 2,         (',', 'or'): 1,
         ('or', 'not'): 1, ('not', 'to'): 1,       (',', 'that'): 1,
        ('that', 'is'): 1, ('is', 'the'): 1, ('the', 'question'): 1,
     ('question', ':'): 1 }

Comment: Edited my answer based on what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

For this task you can use nltk library as follows.

```
    import nltk
    text = ['to','be',',','or','not','to','be',',','that','is','the','question',':']
    print(list(nltk.bigrams(text)))
```

Comment: thanks for your respond .Is it possible to use another way that do not require nltk?

Comment: You can. However usage of nltk library for tokenization as well as generate bi word is better.

Comment: I edited the answer because  no need of removing duplicate words (also the way I did it wrong because then order of list change) as I mentioned earlier. You have to remove common words such as the,a,is if you planning to use this bigrams for nlp or query match  task.